# Matching new set of data with pre-defined sets

Tags: regression, data-analysis

I have sets of data describing sets of levels of requirements needed for certain sets of tasks. The following is a tabulated example:
[image]

Note that the data values are on a scale from 0 to 10.

My problem here is that I have a set of employees whose skills (analysis, patience, comprehension ...) have been analyzed, like the following employee:

- Analysis --> 8.5
- Patience --> 5
- Comprehension --> 7
- Communication --> 7.5
- Creativity --> 8

How to match this employee to the best task according to his skillset and the required ones for each task and also find a matching percentage.

Please note that the number of tasks is much bigger (around 1000 tasks) with more requirements that have been found statistically.

Comment: What would be interesting is if you could measure how well different employees 'perform' at certain tasks. That way you could do away with specifying the type of person needed for the task, and use ML to learn what employees would do well at certain tasks.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need Machine Learning for doing this.

You can subtract the vector describing the user to the vector of the task, and calculate the magnitude of those vectors.

The vector with the smallest magnitude will come from the most matching task.

Comment: Yes i thought of this approach but the problem is that the two vectors aren't always equal, in some instances some skills of the employee are yet to be calculated. A for loop can be used to subtract and filter each missing element out but a concern of the computation time is raised for this approach.

Comment: If the value is missing, you need to use business logic to decide what makes sense - I'd probably set it to zero as I wouldn't assign some tasks to people whose skills are unknown.

Comment: Yes I agree and this is the method currently implemented, but I'm looking for another way that takes into account this discrepancy automatically in order to save time (something similar to logistic regression or logistic regression itself if it applies)

Comment: If you want to use some kind of model, then you also would require some kind of output metric. For example, if someone with a certain set of scores is usually really good at one of the tasks, a model would tell you quickly to place a new person with those skills in that task. You at least need to be able to specify what a good match would be to perform _unsupervised learning_. With the data as you present it, an analytical solution seems most fitting. You can take the discrepancy into account with that too, and it will likely run faster than an ML model.

Comment: Yes you're right, now regarding the set of good scores for a certain tasks, the scores are actually defined and what you said is exactly what I want. A way to match a new person with the best task. The analytical solution is considered you are 100% right, but I want to find different models and methods to evaluate my options.

Answer (score 0):

As a follow up to my question and after some research, I have found a programmatic approach using Python on this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32446703/find-closest-vector-from-a-list-of-vectors-python

It basically describes a way to use Python spacial scipy library.
The approach is fairly simple, you input a set of vectors, create a KDTree and finally query the tree with an input vector. But one inconvenience arises: the input vector should be of the same length as the other vectors so some pre-processing is required.

The code used is:

```
>>> from scipy import spatial
>>> A = [[0,1,2,3,4], [4,3,2,1,0], [2,5,3,7,1], [1,0,1,0,1]]
>>> tree = spatial.KDTree(A)
>>> tree.query([0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5]) (1.1180339887498949, 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking cue from answer by `Vincenzo Lavorini`, following is the python code for finding task closest to employee's abilities:

```
import numpy as np

# Let tt be list of tasks and ee be employee: 
tt = [[0,1,2,3,4], [4,3,2,1,0], [2,5,3,7,1], [1,0,1,0,1]]
ee = [0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5]

# convert to numpy array: 
tt = np.array(tt)
ee = np.array(ee)

# find difference between each task and employee:
res = tt - ee
print(res)
```

Output:

```
[[-0.5  0.5  1.5  2.5  3.5]
 [ 3.5  2.5  1.5  0.5 -0.5]
 [ 1.5  4.5  2.5  6.5  0.5]
 [ 0.5 -0.5  0.5 -0.5  0.5]]
```

Find total differences:

```
res = [np.sum(x) for x in res]
print(res)
```

Output:

```
[7.5, 7.5, 15.5, 0.5]
```

Find index number of task with minimum total difference using `numpy.argmin`:

```
print("Task number most suited for this employee:", np.argmin(res))
```

Output:

```
Task number most suited for this employee: 3
```

The result is same as that from `scipy spatial` code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sometimes missing some measurements of certain skills for certain employees, you can impute them, assuming the missingness happens at random (ie. a certain skill measurement being missing does not indicate the employee is likely to actually be better/worse at that skill).  The imputation would infer missing skill values based on the observed skill values for that employee. You could use multiple imputation here to capture the distribution of information you don't know, my favorite approach is Multiple Imputation Via Chained Equations (MICE).